# python pandas float64 to object after using fillna

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

After reading CSV file and after fillna('') my TransactionBatch column value converted into scientific format. Please advice how to fix this issue.

Screenshot for your reference [image: float_to_object]

**CSV file content.**
"UID","Date","Description","DisbursementAccount","TransactionBatch","ReceiptNumber","Amount"
"ID1",2013-02-01 12:00:00,"FEE CHANGED","R001","2013084","00",6100.0000
"ID2",,,,,,
"ID3",2008-11-03 12:00:00,"RECEIPT","R001","2009008","1089621",39.0000

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'G:\20190904_071321_FH.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8')

print (df['TransactionBatch'].head())
df.fillna('', inplace=True)

print (df['TransactionBatch'].head())
```

Comment: Why would you fill `NaN` with an empty string?

Comment: I have to do some change tracking and compare df value with DB to get changed value.

Answer (score 0):

Your numbers didn't change: you now have a mixed type column (2 floats and 1 string) which is shown as object. You can verify this by

```
df.fillna('').applymap(type)
#0  <class 'float'>
#1    <class 'str'>
#2  <class 'float'>
```

To change the floating point numbers display format you can use:

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.1f}'.format
```

Comment: When I output this df in csv its value comes as scientific

Comment: @MarkWang: I agree completely and I didn't say that it'd be a good idea, just answering the OP question (I don't understand either why he would like to replace NaNs with '')

Comment: @SachinJain: did you set the display format as shown in my answer? (the `to_csv()` parameter `float_format` takes no effect here as it's an object and not a float column)

Comment: Yes. my problem still exist. Looking for some another workaround.